# Key error while trying to iterate over two pd dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First of all, apologies because the reason for the problem may be very obvious.

I have two data frames, df_1 and df_2

[df_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7NS9.png)

[df_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exh7g.png)

I am trying to iterate over both in such a way that when comparing df_1['location_name'] and df_2['Country Name'], if they are equal I copy the value corresponding to the year in a new column df_1['GDP'].

I have tried to do it with the following code:

```
 for i in df_1['location_name']:
    for j in df_2.iloc[0, 4:]:
        for k in df_2['Country Name']:
            if df_1['location_name'][i] == df_2['Country Name'][j]:
                df_1['GDP'][i] = df_2.iloc[len(k),4 + len(k)]
            else:
                df_1['GDP'][i] = 'NaN'
```

But I get this error:

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/downgrade/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~/anaconda3/envs/downgrade/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Afghanistan'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3843/2045004049.py in <module>
      2     for j in df_2.iloc[0, 4:]:
      3         for k in df_2['Country Name']:
----> 4             if df_1['location_name'][i] == df_2['Country Name'][j]:
      5                 df_1['GDP'][i] = df_2.iloc[len(k),4 + len(k)]
      6             else:
...
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'Afghanistan'
```

If anyone could help me with this, I would be very grateful.

Regards!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why aren't you using merge for this sort of operation? This loop with get very slow very fast when/if your dataset grows.